# Setting images in ListView rows conditionally

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I have an `AsyncTask` that in `onPostExecute()` sets an adapter for a `ListView`.
I use `SimpleAdapter`:

```
protected void onPostExecute(List<Map<String, String>> result) {
    super.onPostExecute(result);

    Activity act = parent.getActivity();
    Toast.makeText(act.getApplicationContext(), act.getString(R.string.results_completed), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter (
            parent.getActivity(), 
            result, 
            R.layout.fragment_results_list_item, 
            RESULTS_MAPPINGS, 
            RESULTS_VIEWS }
    );

    parent.setListAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Here `parent` is a `ListFragment`.

Each row in the `ListView` has an image and some text.
I can set the image calling [setViewImage(ImageView v, String s)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleAdapter.html#setViewImage) and specifying an image resource, but this image will be the same for all rows.

What I want is to set the image *conditionally*. There is one particular key in every `Map<String, String>` inside the list `result` whose value will be either `"0"` or `"1"`. Depending on this value I want to set the image for that particular row to be one (local) image resource or another.

What is the best way to accomplish this? (The only way I can think of is to set first always the same image, and once the `AsyncTask` has completely executed, iterate through the maps in the `ListFragment` and change those that need to be changed.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might need to use a `BaseAdapter`, and specify which image to use in `getView`. [Here](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html) is a good tutorial.

The idea is do to something like:

```
@Override
public View getView(int id, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder viewHolder;

    if (view == null) {
        view = <inflate your layout>;

        viewHolder = new viewHolder();
        viewHolder.imageView = view.findViewById(<imageViewId>);

        view.setTag(viewHolder);
    } else {
        viewHodler = (ViewHoler) view.getTag();
    }

    if (content.getKey(id) == 0) { // content in your Map<>
        viewHolder.imageView.setImage(<image0>);
    } else {
        viewHolder.imageView.setImage(<image1>);
    }

    return view;
 }

 private static ViewHolder {
     public ImageView imageView;
 }
```